# Checking if a matrix is positive matrix after some coordinate transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have the next positive definite matrix $Q\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$. For a full rank $U$ (e.g. defining a linear coordinate transformation) I can decompose $Q$ as
$$
Q = U^{-1}TU,
$$
where obviously $Q$ and $T$ are similar, but $T$ in general is not symmetric and then it is not positive definite.

Consider the rotation matrix
$$
R(\theta) = \begin{bmatrix}sin(\theta) & cos(\theta) & 0 \\ -cos(\theta) & sin(\theta) & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix},
$$
and decompose $T$ as
$$
T = R^T\tilde TR,
$$
then we have the next relation
$$
Q = U^{-1}R^T\tilde TRU.
$$
And now decompose $U = R^T\tilde UR$, and therefore $U^{-1}=R^T\tilde U^{-1}R$. Substituting into the before equation we have
$$
Q = R^T\tilde U^{-1} \tilde T \tilde U R \\
RQR^T = \tilde U^{-1} \tilde T \tilde U.
$$
We know that $Q$ is similar to $\tilde U^{-1} \tilde T \tilde U$. So If $RQR^T$ is symmetric then $\tilde U^{-1} \tilde T \tilde U$ is positive definite.

But I cannot see why in general, for whatever rotation matrix (or even a more general set, orthogonal transformations?) $RQR^T$ is a symmetric matrix. My numerical simulations suggest that this is indeed the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the property

$$(AB)^t=B^tA^t$$

Comment: ohh, it was so easy! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using tensor notation$$(RQR^T)_{ij}=R_{ik}Q_{kl}R^T_{lj}=R_{ik}Q_{kl}R_{jl}=R_{ik}Q_{lk}R_{jl}=R_{jl}Q_{lk}R_{ik}=R_{jl}Q_{lk}R^T_{ki}=(RQR^T)_{ji}$$